# Ground State Energy of Quantum Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

Letting $u=rR(r)$, the radial part of the SE becomes:

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}u_{rr}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2r^2 u+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}u=Eu$$

I am interested in obtaining the energy of the ground state (which I know is $3\hbar \omega/2$). As such, I set $l=0$ to get

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}u_{rr}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2r^2 u=Eu$$

which is identical the 1D harmonic oscillator problem. The lowest energy of the 1D oscillator is $\hbar \omega/2$, which is not the right energy for the 3D case. Why does this method not give me the proper energy for the 3D case? How can I find the ground state energy using the spherical equations?

Comment: Not sure where you get your first formula from. The potential energy for a 1D QHO is given by $V(x)=\frac12 m\omega^2x^2$. See: http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node15.html, the ground state energy is indeed $\frac32 \hbar \omega$.

Comment: @Gert See the penultimate equation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_spherically_symmetric_potential#Relationship_with_1-D_Schr.C3.B6dinger_equation

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hframe.html

Comment: @Gert That is just a frame. What was the page you meant to link me to?

Comment: Sorry: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hosc.html#c1

Comment: @Gert I know that the energy is $(n+1/2)\hbar \omega$ in the 1D case and $(n+3/2)\hbar \omega$ in the 3D case by using Cartesian coordinates. What I am trying to figure out is why when I use spherical coordinates in 3D, I get that the ground state energy is $\hbar\omega/2$ using the method I described.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/248365/three-dimensional-isotropic-harmonic-oscilator-hamiltonian/248444#248444

Comment: I'm not sure, But I think the problem arises because it is not justified to put $l=0$ before solving the equation. Three-dimensional isotropic oscillators are solved in books. For example,  in Quantum Mechanics by Bransden and Joachain.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you obtain an equation for $u$ that is exactly equal to the equation for the 1D harmonic oscillator; what changes are boundary conditions.
In fact, in solving these kind of equations, you require that the radial solution $R(r)$ goes like a certain power, that turns out to be
$$
R(r) \xrightarrow[r \to 0]{} r^l\, .
$$
Then necessarily we have $u(r)\xrightarrow[r \to 0]{} r^{l+1}$, that in particular for $l=0$ means
$$
u(0)=0\,, \qquad u(r)\xrightarrow[r \to 0]{} r \, \,.
$$

From here it can be noticed that this solution **does not** correspond to the ground state of the 1D harmonic oscillator, that being a Gaussian is not null at $r=0$.

The first eigenfunction of the 1D harmonic oscillator that fulfills the boundary conditions is actually the one corresponding to $n=1$, with an energy given by
$$
E=\hbar \omega\left(1+\frac12\right)= \frac32 \hbar \omega \, ,
$$
which is the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the boundary conditions: in the spherical problem, the radius $r$ is necessarily $\ge 0$ and it is not possible to have a wavefunction for $r<0$.  This forces the eigenfunction to have a node at $r=0$ so the solution does not “leak” into $r<0$, just like they must have a node at both ends of an infinite well since the wavefunctions cannot beyond the well.

As a result, the lowest eigenfunction allowed by the boundary condition is the lowest solution with a node at $r=0$, and this is the harmonic oscillator solution with energy $\frac{3}{2}\hbar\omega$.  Note also that, as a result, the next $\ell=0$ solution will occur at $\frac{7}{2}\hbar \omega$, since the energy $\frac{5}{2}\hbar \omega$ corresponds to a solution that does not satisfy the boundary condition at $r=0$.  Of course there are solutions with this energy $\frac{5}{2}\hbar \omega$: they just don’t have $\ell=0$.